# How to determine the result of a logical operator on nullable booleans?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, boolean

In C#, for example, when I compare two nullable booleans (`bool?`) I get the following results :

```
true & null = null
false & null = false
true | null = true
false | null = null
```

The issue is that I couldn't understand how those results come, what's the rule which I can use to determine the result of a logical operator on two booleans, when one of them is null?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is that "null" means "unknown" here, or "not enough information". So if the answer depends on the unknown value, the answer itself is unknown. If the answer will be the same whatever the unknown value is (e.g. `true | null`) then you're still okay.

Think of it this way:

```
y = true & x; // the result will be the same as the value of x (it depends on x)
y = true | x; // the result will be true whatever x is
```

Comment: I think you meant `it has to be x` instead of `it has to be true` on the first comment, i.e y will be whatever x will be.

Comment: @GDS: Well, I meant "x has to be true for y to be true" really, but I'll edit for clarity.